# How to set jQuery validation depending on the dropdown list?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validation. I have a form and fields are `name, mobile, email, and select status`.

The select status is the dropdown with options `confirmed, pending, and cancel`.

Now My issue is if the user selects the `confirmed` then mobile and the email field needs to be required and if select rest of options from select then fields should not be required.

I mean, I select confirmed from the dropdown then require validation on email and mobile fields. If select other option then not validation on mobile and email.

Would you help me out with this issue?

```js
$("#form1").validate({
  rules: {

    name: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 3
    },

    mobileno: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 10,
      maxlength: 10,
      number: true
    },

    emailid: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },

    status: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    //rest my code here
  }


});
```

```html
<form action="#" name="form1" id="form1" method="post" autocomplete="off">

  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="text" name="mobileno" id="mobileno" placeholder="mobileno">
  <input type="email" name="emailid" id="emailid" placeholder="email">
  <select class="" name="status">
    <option selected disabled> Select Status</option>
    <option value="1">Confirmed</option>
    <option value="2">Pending</option>
    <option value="3">Cancel</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit">
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple things to note, you need to set the value of your select element's default to an empty string rather than making it disabled for it to work properly with jQuery Validate. Also, if you're using the same depends logic on multiple fields, you should abstract it into its own function.

```js
function isRequiredBySelection() {
   var selectedVal = $('select[name="status"]').val();
   return selectedVal === '1' || selectedVal === '3';
}

$("#form1").validate({
  rules: {
    name: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 3
    },

    mobileno: {
      required: {
       depends: isRequiredBySelection
      },
      minlength: 10,
      maxlength: 10,
      number: true
    },

    emailid: {
      required: {
       depends: isRequiredBySelection
      },
      email: true
    },

    status: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form)
  {
    //You code here
  }  
});
```

```html
<form action="#" name="form1" id="form1" method="post" autocomplete="off">

  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="text" name="mobileno" id="mobileno" placeholder="mobileno">
  <input type="email" name="emailid" id="emailid" placeholder="email">
  <select class="" name="status">
    <option value=""> Select Status</option>
    <option value="1">Confirmed</option>
    <option value="2">Pending</option>
    <option value="3">Cancel</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit">
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery validation API gives this example:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    contact: {
      required: true,
      email: {
        depends: function(element) {
          return $("#contactform_email").is(":checked");
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

*DEMO with your code IS UNTESTED*

#### DEMO:

```js
$("#form1").validate({
  rules: {

    name: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 3
    },

    mobileno: {
      required: {
          depends: function(element) {
             let myval = $('select[name=status]').val();
             let ok2go = (myval==1 || myval==3) ? true : false;
             return ok2go;
          },
      minlength: 10,
      maxlength: 10,
      number: true
    },

    emailid: {
      required: {
          depends: function(element) {
             let myval = $('select[name=status]').val();
             return (myval==1 || myval==3) ? true : false;
          },
      email: true
    },

    status: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    //rest my code here
  }


});
```

```html
<form action="#" name="form1" id="form1" method="post" autocomplete="off">

  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="text" name="mobileno" id="mobileno" placeholder="mobileno">
  <input type="email" name="emailid" id="emailid" placeholder="email">
  <select class="" name="status">
    <option selected disabled> Select Status</option>
    <option value="1">Confirmed</option>
    <option value="2">Pending</option>
    <option value="3">Cancel</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit">
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

#### Reference:

https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Comment: Give me some time to check your answer

Comment: I checked your snippet, it's not working...even I try your code on local but not working.

Comment: yes, I tried but not working... I think I found my answer using                 required: {
                    depends: function () {
                        return $('#status').val() == "1";
                    }
                }

Comment: Yes, sure please update it...and one more thing I have to ask. If the val is 1 then validation work. Is it possible for more than one val? Like I have to set validation when 1 0r 3 option selected.

Comment: I further modified the example to use a ternary - same result, less code. *(Could reduce by one more line, but that might make it overly cryptic.)* AFK for a bit.

Comment: You're welcome. I edited the `emailid` one to show how to use the one-line-further-reduced version.

Comment: Your snippet is not working.